# what it is called placing an button/image button on border of layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, imagebutton

[image]

Does anyone knows what it is called placing that capture button at the border of that layout

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. And also you should try to write the code yourself first...

Comment: @Vucko can you see my question again as i have edited it

Comment: It's called the parent layout beeing a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create an FrameLayout which will contain (among other things) layout that placed in the bottom in your screenshot and button with bottom margin equals to half of height of that layout. Something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Many other sub-layouts -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <!-- bottom bar icons. you can use not Frame but every layout. -->
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- you can use any widget. Not necessary Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo_button"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```